# The script is not saving my bad_responses correctly

Tags: python, pandas, rest, for-loop, indentation

I have brainstormed a lot of possibilities and created a bulk API call so I can import some products into my store. It works fine, products are imported correctly, however, I have trouble saving bad responses in a csv file.

Maybe I am doing something wrong or my indentation is not correct. Please, point me in a right direction or provide any advice for the future for not making similar mistakes.

This is the code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('edited_csv.csv')
bad_responses_list = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    endpoint = f"{base_url}/products"
    data = {
            "product_id": int(df['product_id'][i]),
            "title": df['title'][i],
            "discount_type": "percentage",
            "discount": 5, 
        }
        }
    response = requests.post(endpoint, json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
    status_code = response.status_code
    if status_code != 200 or status_code != 201:
        bad_responses_list.append([df['product_id'][i], response.status_code])

df_bad_responses = pd.DataFrame(bad_responses_list, columns=['product_id', 'status_code'])
df_bad_responses.to_csv('products_with_bad_responses.csv')
```

Now, when I run this it creates csv with good and bad responses, something like this:

```
product_id, status_code
7262783, 201
9458389, 201
0493788, 422
7273628, 422
7263728, 201
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

the `or` in this line:

```py
if status_code != 200 or status_code != 201:
```

needs to be an `and`